# Pointers & Dynamic Memory Allocation in C

Tags: c, malloc, args

I'm fairly new to the language C and am getting a bit muddled up with pointers & dynamic memory allocation. What I'm trying to do is read in command line arguments and store them in dynamic memory allocation; then printing them out. For example if I typed ./rpd 4 3 2 3 8 then argv[1] (4) should be decremented and the other 3 values (3, 2, 3, 8) should follow. The output should look like:

Person 1 has 3 cars.
Person 2 has 2 cars.
Person 3 has 3 cars.
Person 4 has 8 cars.

My Code is:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /** argc is number of arguments at command line*/
    /** argv[] is an array of pointers to character strings
        i.e. argv 1 points to argc 1 */
    int numberOfCars;
    char *person;
    int i;
    int j;

    // Allocate the size of the array for each element of char
    person = malloc(sizeof(numberOfCars) *argc);

    for(i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
        /** Convert char to int */
        numberOfCars = atoi(argv[i]);
        person = atoi(argv[1]);
        if(person > 0){
            for(j = 2; j < person; j--) {
                printf("Person %d has %d cars \n", person--, numberOfCars);
            }
        } else {
            /** DO NOTHING */
        }
    }
    return person;
}
```

I'm sorry if this is a little confusing (or naive) of me; but I am extremely new to this language so I'm still trying to get my head around everything.

Thanks alot for any help :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `person = atoi(argv[1]);`that one does not make sense. person is of type `char*`and atoi() returns an integer. Please explain how you expect your program to behave

Comment: Two things right off the bat, you need `<stdlib.h>` for `malloc`. You also seem to be allocating memory to `person` through `malloc` and then overwriting it with your call to `atoi`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /** argc is number of arguments at command line*/
    /** argv[] is an array of pointers to character strings
        i.e. argv 1 points to argc 1 */
    int numberOfCars;
    int i;

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        /** Convert char to int */
        numberOfCars = atoi(argv[i]);
        printf("Person %d has %d cars \n", i, numberOfCars);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then tweak it for your needs. You dont need to specify the number of people for the first input argument, since it's implied by the number of cars you specify for each person.

Answer (score 0):

`atoi`returns an int, but `person` is a char pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   /** argc is number of arguments at command line*/
   /** argv[] is an array of pointers to character strings
    i.e. argv 1 points to argc 1 */
   int numberOfCars;
   int i;
   int p = 0;
   for(i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
      /** Convert char to int */
      numberOfCars = atoi(argv[i]);
      printf("Person %d has %d cars \n", ++p, numberOfCars);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 4 3 2 3 8 10
 Person 1 has 3 cars 
 Person 2 has 2 cars   
 Person 3 has 3 cars 
 Person 4 has 8 cars 
 Person 5 has 10 cars
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numberOfCars;
    int *person;
    int i;

    person = malloc(sizeof(int) * argc);

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        numberOfCars = atoi(argv[i]);
        if (i == 1)
            numberOfCars--;
        person[i] = numberOfCars;
        printf("Person %d has %d cars\n", i, numberOfCars);
    }

    free(person);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample output

```
$ ./rpd 4 3 2 3 8
Person 1 has 3 cars 
Person 2 has 3 cars 
Person 3 has 2 cars 
Person 4 has 3 cars 
Person 5 has 8 cars
$
```

#### Explanation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

You need `<stdlib.h>` to declare `malloc()` and `free()`.  When you use `malloc()`, you should also use `free()`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numberOfCars;
    int *person;
    int i;
```

The variable `j` is unused in the revision and therefore removed.  The variable `person` is changed to `int *` as `person[i]` will store the number of cars person `i` has.

```
    person = malloc(sizeof(int) * argc);
```

I changed the `sizeof()` to `int`; it would also be possible to use `sizeof(*person)` and there are good reasons for preferring that.

```
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        numberOfCars = atoi(argv[i]);
```

The assignment `person = atoi(argv[1]);` was erroneous at multiple levels. It leaked the memory assigned by the `malloc()`; it assigned an `int` to a pointer (originally a `char *`).

```
        if (i == 1)
            numberOfCars--;
```

This deals with the 'subtract one from first argument' requirement.

```
        person[i] = numberOfCars;
```

This records the number of cars that person `i` has.  It isn't used; it could be used in place of `numberOfCars` in the `printf()` statement.

```
        printf("Person %d has %d cars\n", i, numberOfCars);
```

Spaces at the end of a line are a bête noire of mine.  Don't put blanks before a newline.

```
    }

    free(person);
```

Release the memory that was allocated.  In this toy program, it isn't critical (the o/s is about to release all the resources used by the program), but if it was a function in a big program and it omitted the `free()`, it would leak memory each time it is called.  Get into the habit of writing the `free()` for each `malloc()` as soon as you've written the `malloc()`.  (Or, at least, make sure you know where you will write the `free()`, and *do* write the `free()` before compiling, let alone testing, the program.)

```
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to store dynamically?
If want to only print the values as you mentioned in question. You would not require dynamic allocation at all.

If at all you want to store them use 
char **person; //instead of *person and keep allocation memory per person by using

person[i] = malloc(sizeof(argv[i])+sizeof("person has cars")); //not sure of ur required format to store you can change it accordingly